# eSata enclosures can reach 6Gn/s

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, esata

I have an relatively older eSata external enclosure that works OK. But I'm planning now to swap the hard disk for a SSD, and wonder if I should update the eSata enclosure too. In principle I understand that, if the mainboard supports SATA-600 and the disk too, the eSata shouldn't slow the show. But, searching for info, I've seen some enclosures that rate the maximum eSata speed as 3Gb/s, so I'm not sure if there can be circuitry in the enclosure that could act as bottleneck, and I should better buy a new enclosure. I cannot anyway find anything like enclosures rated at 6Gb/s. Most have no rating, and some 3Gb/s.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.startech.com/HDD/Enclosures/USB-3-eSATA-Trayless-HDD-Enclosure-UASP~S3510BMU33ET

This is the only enclosure I found that has E-Sata 6Gb/s.